# Difference between ground potential and actual connection to earth?

Tags: electrostatics

Hello people I am really struggling with electrostatics... In Griffith, when a conductor is grounded it simply means to set the potential to 0V. So this can be used as a boundary condition for solving Poisson's equation. But there is a difference when I connect a wire physically from earth to the conductor I assume? Now I can "use" the charges that earth provides to neutralize charges within the conductor. This would not be possible if I simply set the potential to 0V "mathematically" because the conductor is still seen as isolated from earth

Answer (score 1):

The physical connection to earth that is present in electrical outlets in most countries is a *safety* ground. It's purpose is to reduce the risk of electrocution and fire in the event of a fault in the building wiring or in electrified equipment. Ideally, if a fault occurs, excess current flows through the ground wire and causes either a fuse to blow or a circuit breaker to trip.

Apart from safety hazards, electrical equipment generally works fine without any connection to actual ground. Certain types of antennas and their associated equipment are exceptional. That is, in some cases, an antenna system relies upon an associated connection to physical ground to work as designed. The rule also applies to some unwanted antennas. A faraday cage is an enclosure that inhibits the passage of electromagnetic radiation from inside the cage to the outside, or from the outside to the inside. In some cases, a faraday cage will not work effectively if it  is not connected to physical ground. Certain cabling arrangements are designed so that the outer conductor of a coaxial cable acts as a faraday cage to shield signals on the inner conductor (or to shield the outer world from electromagetic interference from signals on the inner conductor). Such cabling arrangements may not work properly if the outer conductor is not connected to physical ground.